# Retornando manager no template (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates

Como eu faço para retornar a quantidade de livros publicados no template?

Eu tenho isso

```
# models.py
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):

    def published(self):
        return self.filter(published=True)


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('nome', max_length=50)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author', verbose_name='autores')
    published = models.BooleanField('publicado', default=True)
    # add our custom model manager
    objects = PublishedManager()
```

e

```
#views.py
class BookList(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'books'
    paginate_by = 10
```

Tentei isso

```
# template.html
<p>Livros publicados: {{ books.published.count }}</p>
```

Mas não foi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regis,

eu desconheço uma maneira de fazer isso que você quer sem criar um novo filtro, ou alterar o contexto da sua View.

Para criar um novo filtro você pode olhar a [documentação do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/), mas bem resumido você faria assim:

Primeiro você registra o seu novo filtro:

```
@register.filter
def count_published(value):
    return value.filter(published=True).count()
```

Depois você utiliza ele no template:

```
{% load seu_arquivo_de_template_tags %}
<p>Livros publicados: {{ books | count_published }}</p>
```

Existe uma outra maneira de se fazer também que seria a modificação da `get_context_data` da sua `ListView`:

```
class BookList(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'books'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['count_published'] = self.model.objects.filter(published=True).count()
        return context
```

E depois utilizar no seu template a variável de contexto que você passou:

```
<p>Livros publicados: {{ count_published }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça isso no view.py

```
#views.py
class BookList(ListView):

    # ...

    books_published = Book.objects.filter(published=True)
```

e no template:

```
# template.html
<p>Livros publicados: {{ books_published|length }}</p>
```